# PHP Secure Login - password encryption

Tags: php, security, password-protection, login-script

Here is the login system to which the secure login is to be implemented/

```
main_login.php

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" /> <br />
    Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

Checklogin.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="cosmos"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['username'] == $myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful. <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_destroy();

header("location:main_login.php");
?>
```

the problem is that I want to make this secure login by password encryption or any other method (if any). I am beginner to PHP

Comment: what exactly you want to encrypt and why?

Comment: You should use the type `password` for password input fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can encrypt the password to a degree with md5. You would need to md5 the password from when the user signs up and before the login md5....

Example:
 
`// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);`

You would also need to use this whenever you have a user sign up.

Comment: This is horrendously insecure. you should be using a stronger hashing algorithm (like bcrypt). also your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner, most likely you do not need any encryption. Especially because it would be Javascript, not PHP.
Though it can be done.
You could use hashed challenge implementing Digest authentication schema

- server send a challenge - a random strimg
- client make a hash of this challenge and a password
- this hash being sent to server
- server doing a hash the same way and compare both

There are a lot of Javascript MD5 hashing algorithm implementations over internet.

Of course, an SSL certificate would be preferred over this homemade implementation.

But to get proper answer, you still need to clarify what exactly you want to encrypt and why. And why don't you concerned about securing something else. Your whole database for example.

Some notes for a while.
Your login_success code would either not work and protect nothing.
It should be just

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
```

because there is no $myusername variable to compare.
And there ought to be `exit;` right after `header("location:...`
Or a client will get protected contents anyway

Comment: The homemade implementation can be defeated with a man-in-the-middle attack. Still, it's secure against eavesdropping.

Comment: @Georg how come? I see no way

Comment: A man-in-the-middle can either modify the Javascript sent to the client (e.g. remove encryption code) or pose as the server. A true SSL secured connection works with certificates to make sure that the server your talking to is indeed the server you want to talk to.

Answer (score 2):

To make this a little more secure, you should store encrypted passwords in your database and then compare the encrypted entered password with the stored hash. This way if someone somehow accesses the members table, they cannot see the actual passwords.

Suppose the password is `myPassword` then don't just store it, hash it first using an algorithm like `md5` then store the hash which is `deb1536f480475f7d593219aa1afd74c` in your database. Then when user enters a password, hash it and compare two hashes.

For more secure approach, use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: Encryption is reversible; and that’s not a good idea. Better use hashing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use md5($password) or sha1($password) while inserting the signup data to table.

to match again for login login

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='".md5($mypassword)."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

There is some other way too, to protect further. Using combination of sha1 and salt.

By the way why dont you use some quick php framework coz these small things are already built with them.

Thanks

Comment: @tunetosuraj: You're building a CMS while being a PHP beginner? How about you suggest using an opensource CMS that you customize to their needs?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would store a hash of the passwords in the database see [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) however this doesn't make it secure between the webpage and server - for this you need to use https.

There are two things here.

1.
If I'm a dumb user and when I sign up for your site I have to give a password I might give the same password as I used elsewhere so your site should really store a hash of the password instead of the real thing so if they get hacked the attackers won't get my password that I used everywhere. To do this you store the hash in your members table and in the query that checks it is valid you pass a hash instead of the real thing.

2.
Under http the password will get sent from the browser to the server in plain text. If this is over the internet and an attacker has access to any networks in between the browser and client then they can see the password - if you hash it in the browser using javascript the attacker can pick up the hash and possibly use this to login to your site. That is why we have https. For a low cost (especially compared to development costs) you can buy a certificate that will secure the connection. If you don't want to do this you can self sign a certificate and use this. If your hosting does not allow you to use a certificate then it might be possible to create a home brew solution but it is much better to just find other hosting.

Comment: ok I am really bad at this
but I wanna know if for example due to some reason I dont have access to SSL then how do I use hash method? I mean i have to create a sign up page using md5 function and all, can you explain that...

Comment: @tune SSL has nothing to do here anyway. it is protected password storage, not login system everyone is talking about.

Comment: see my edit - but as someone else has mentioned maybe you should try out some open source cms before trying to implement your own.

Answer (score -2):

md5 would be the best in this case. Run the Input Details such as Password through the MD5 function and insert into your database.

Its nearly unreverseable so the only way to use it is to use MD5 on login also and compair the md5 password from login with the version stored in the database.